# popBackStack with dismissing onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I am trying to convert my IOS app to android, and I am a little new in android. My app navigates between fragments generally with the navigation drawer. When I am at fragment A, and then go to fragment B, and then press the back button, with the codes below it goes back to fragment A. However, when I go to fragment A with the back button, it loads again from the beginning. Is there a way that it goes back to previous fragment without loading the class again that the previous info in the fragment will be shown? It would be great if anyone could help about this?

This is the code when the back button is pressed:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else {

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {

                fm.popBackStack();

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("no more back");
            }

        }
    }
```

This is how I navigate between fragments:

```
usersFragment fragment = new usersFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Use

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourTag"));
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

instead of

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

Its because *replace* remove current fragment and add next fragment. So when coming back it recreate previous fragment again.

Comment: Hello nitinkumarp, thank you, but in this way once the fragment is created, how will you reload it again if necessarry? I want this behaviour only when the back button is pressed, but when I come to the fragment with a link from another page, even if it was loaded before, it should load again. In IOS when you press the back button between UiViews, it just does it automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much nitinkumarp, it worked great:) By the way, rather than using it as tag, I used "findFragmentById".

Comment: Yeah you could findFragmentById also. Good luck for your app :)